Update EmbedOne to null value
I have problem with updating my documents data. In my data model a have EmbedOne field which is nullable. When I want to set it to null value update does not work.
I found in PersintenceBuilder.php on row. 244 this part of code:
// Fields with a null value should only be written for inserts
if ($new === null) {
   if ($mapping['nullable'] === true) {
        $updateData['$setOnInsert'][$mapping['name']] = null;
   }
   continue;
}

Is there some workaround to set it to null value?
My data model for this field looks like this:
#[MongoDB\EmbedOne(nullable: true, targetDocument: SomeObject::class)]
private ?SomeObject $someObject = null;

Thanks
